# Boostrap-vue Carousel sliding bug

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, carousel, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm experiencing a bug while using Boostrap(4)-Vue.

Namely, when transitioning between slides the image scrolls up and the page 'jumps' as can be seen below. I've copied exactly the source code in the [reference provided](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/carousel/).

The bug persists in both Chromium and Firefox, both for desktop (large) view and for mobile.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Vue component:

```
<template>
    <b-carousel id="carousel1"
                style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
                controls
                indicators
                background="#ababab"
                :interval="4000"
                img-width="1024"
                img-height="480"
                v-model="slide"
                @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
                @sliding-end="onSlideEnd">

      <!-- Text slides with image -->
      <b-carousel-slide caption="First slide"
                        text="Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum."
                        img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=52"
      ></b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with custom text -->
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=54">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with image only -->
      <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=58">
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slides with img slot -->
      <!-- Note the classes .d-block and .img-fluid to prevent browser default image alignment -->
      <b-carousel-slide>
        <img slot="img" class="d-block img-fluid w-100" width="1024" height="480"
             src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=55" alt="image slot">
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <!-- Slide with blank fluid image to maintain slide aspect ratio -->
      <b-carousel-slide caption="Blank Image" img-blank img-alt="Blank image">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
          eros felis, tincidunt a tincidunt eget, convallis vel est. Ut pellentesque
          ut lacus vel interdum.
        </p>
      </b-carousel-slide>

    </b-carousel>
</template>

<script>
import data from '@/data'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data () {
    return {
      slogan: data.slogan,
      welcome: data.welcome,
      servicesList: data.servicesList,
      slide: 0,
      sliding: true,
      selected: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    expand (sect) {
      sect.expanded = !sect.expanded
    },
    onSlideStart (slide) {
      this.sliding = true
    },
    onSlideEnd (slide) {
      this.sliding = false
    }

  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}

.selected {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
</style>
```

[image: Buggy behaviour]

Comment: give me your code in https://codesandbox.io/s/vue so i can help you on that

Comment: @NishargShah I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl2qj55vrm), but unfortunately the issue is not present there. Anything else I can try?

Comment: so i think this is height problem in your carousel, check your style again